# adaptation of Hahn-Banach for destination space $\ne \Bbb R$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, hahn-banach-theorem

Let $E$ be a Banach space, $H$ a Hilbert space, $F ⊂ H$ is a closed non-dense subspace,  and $ S ∈ \mathcal L(F, E)$. Prove it exists $ T ∈ \mathcal L(H, E)$ s.t.
$\|T\| = \|S\|$ and $T (x) = S(x) ∀x ∈ F $.

This would be a corollary of Hahn-Banach theorem if we had $E=\Bbb R$ but I don't see how to adapt the setup of this problem to the analytic version of Hahn-Banach. Or maybe there is other way than Hahn-Banach?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It's good to keep in mind that you never "need" the Hahn-Banach theorem in a Hilbert space, because thanks to the Riesz representation theorem there is an explicit description of your functional, leading to an obvious explicit extension.  And that is basically the same idea used in daw's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you can uniquely extent $T$ to $\bar F$. Then use the orthogonal decomposition of $H = \bar F \oplus F^\perp$ and set $T=0$ on $F^\perp$.

Comment: $F$ here is already closed so the first step is not necessary.

Comment: Misread the question...